# Charge 5,4V supercap with 12V solar panel

Tags: zener, supercapacitor, solar-energy, schottky

I'm building a circuit to charge a series of two supercap (500F, 2.7V each) with a solar panel (wich outputs, not sc, 18V@1.5A with direct sunlight at 12pm). Those supercap will then power an esp8266 and a WS2812b strip of 5 led during night.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpvcSE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've drawn this circuit to charge the supercaps, with D1 in parallel to them to stop charge when they reach 5.1V and D2 to prevent supercaps discharge during night time, when D1 should be a closed circuit, due to low voltage from solar panel (is this right?).

Because i'm using a 1N5231B (0,5W power dissipation) do i need to put a series resistor to limit the current from the solar panel? Due to voltage drop across D2, do the 1N5231B works well, or it'll be better something with higher Vz (around 6V maybe)? And last but not least, do i really need D2?

p.s. I'm using SB5100 and 1N5231B only because i already have them.

Comment: The supercaps will **not** divide the voltage equally, you need to use a protection circuit, see how Julian Ilett does that on his Youtube channel: https://www.youtube.com/user/julius256/featured If a resistor is needed (it is unless you want to fry D1 and consequently also the caps), why not draw it in? Using a shunt regulator like this is wasteful, do you also drive your car full throttle and break to adjust the speed? Get a proper switched regulator module, they're only less than $2 delivered from ebay.

Comment: i've tried to charge them with a DC-DC buck converter afer the solar panel but when sunlight is not at its peak, voltage from solar panel will be lower than 18V and so will be at the output of the converter, unless i manually regulate it again

Comment: Uh, you're supposed to set the output of the regulator to 2 * 2.7 V = 5.4 V. Assuming it's a proper **buck converter** the solar panel's voltage can go all the way down to 7 V or so before the output voltage of the converter drops. I suspect that you're not using it (the switched regulator) right.

Comment: What current does the "TO CIRCUIT" load take from the supercaps?

Comment: i'm using this one: https://www.amazon.com/eBoot-MP1584EN-Converter-Adjustable-Module/dp/B01MQGMOKI/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1530626124&sr=8-8&keywords=dc+dc+buck

i can set the output to 5.4V when the solar panel outputs 18V, and it's ok, but when the panel will output 10V buck converter output will not be 5.4V...are they faulty or i'm using them wrong?

Comment: @Andyaka about 0.4A

Comment: Why did you choose these caps and buck converter? These are very poor for efficiency using PV current source.  92% Rating is for an ideal Voltage source. and impedance is not matched and Caps are not balanced

Comment: *about 0.4A* OK, so how long do you think your circuit will work on a set of charged caps? Hint there are "energy in a capacitor" calculators on internet. Also not that discharging to 0 V is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What current does the "TO CIRCUIT" load take from the supercaps?

> @Andyaka about 0.4A

Here's the problem as I see it - your energy equation doesn't stack up - with a net capacitance of 250 farad and a terminal voltage of 5.4 volts, the maximum energy that can be held is 250 x 5.4\$^2\$/2 = 3645 joules.

If your LEDs take 400 mA and require a terminal voltage of 2 volts (very minimal I suspect), the power is 0.8 watts and per hour, that is an energy of 2880 joules. In other words your SCAPs would be dead after 90 minutes.

But it's worse than that because as the SCAPs get discharged of energy their voltage level goes down and this means you can probably only use about 50% of the energy stored in them.

Of course you could employ clever circuits to extract a bit more energy from the depleting SCAPs but you realistically might only get 60 minutes.

Maybe if you considered a load of 60 mA you might get through the night but that then exposes the poor design of the charging circuit - using a zener like this means it will smoke in seconds when the solar panel is on full sunlight - you need a specialist SCAP charger and balancer.

Comment: Ok, you've been more than exaustive!!! Thanks a lot...i'll change my way after i'll have studied more!!

Answer (score 1):

Common failure of Hobby energy ideas that go bad.

1) No specs  ( energy, power , source impedance matching, losses, voltage imbalance , load impedance matching)

2) Choosing parts before understanding expectations from 1) and acceptance criteria.
 - i.e.  Designs are not thrown together and fixed later, or copy what works and make improvements or get help to design from scratch starting with defining specs from 1)

3) not understanding how/where power/energy is lost and failures occur.

## Guestimated Specs

- PV specs = 18Voc @1.5Asc or Zpv(mpt)= 18V/1.5A 12 Ohms ( minimum ) or best case.

  - MPPT vs solar input = 70~85%(?) of Voc = 12.6 to 15.3V
- Solar Energy/day  = 10~150W/day ? check region Solarity Index

  - Avg = 100Wh on a good day ?
- LED load 5V*0.4A =**2Watts,** for x hours = Watt-hours= Joules /3600
- Capacity of SuperCaps from init voltage, V1 to dropout voltage V2 of boost reg.(step-up)

  - e.g. C= 500/2 F,  V1=5.4V (balanced), V2= 2.0V ,
  - \$E=1/2C(V1^2-V2^2)\$[Joules]=[Wh *3600]
  - E=125(29- 4)= **3125 Joules=0.87Wh** or **2 watts for 24 minutes at ~94% efficiency**
  - Lead Acid batteries with 10Ah~12V is 120Wh = > 400,000 Joules.

### Conclusion

- Poor application for PV energy storage for LEDs

### Recommendation

Search for MPPT regulator for suitable lead acid battery ( e.g. 500Wh big car battery)

p.s. when supercaps are fully charged, your zener would have to absorb 27watts (pfft!)